# How to sort ArrayList comparing the distance from current location?

Tags: java

I have a ArrayList of some objects which contains this values

```
String name
String latitude
String longitude
```

I can retrieve my current location, latitude, longitude. Now my question is how can I sort this arraylist comparing with the distance between my current location and the locations of the objects of that arrayList? I can use Comparator to sort arrayList alphabetically but how to do this kind of sorting?

Comment: use a custom comparator and use `Location.distanceBetween`

Comment: Create a `Comparator` and write the necessary comparison logic there. Probably you will need to convert your location (latitude and longitude) in a numeric object e.g. using `BigDecimal` and then do the necessary operations.

Comment: Can someOne give me some code snippet as an example?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a class called `Point` like so:

```
class Point {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
}
```

The comparator can be implemented as follows:

```
class DistanceFromMeComparator implements Comparator<Point> {
    Point me;

    public DistanceFromMeComparator(Point me) {
        this.me = me;
    }

    private Double distanceFromMe(Point p) {
        double theta = p.longitude - me.longitude;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(p.latitude)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(me.latitude))
                + Math.cos(deg2rad(p.latitude)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(me.latitude))
                * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        return dist;
    }

    private double deg2rad(double deg) { return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0); }
    private double rad2deg(double rad) { return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI); }

    @Override
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return distanceFromMe(p1).compareTo(distanceFromMe(p2));
    }
}
```